# Access 'Arguments' in JavaScript V8 Callback

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'd like to be able to access the `Arguments& args` of a callback. Right now when I set the C++ function to be called from the JavaScript side it looks like this:

```
global->Set(String::New("login"), FunctionTemplate::New(Login));
```

And the prototype of the C++ function is:

```
Handle<Value> MyClass::Login(const Arguments& args)
```

How do I access this `Arguments& args` so that I can pass in a variable when the callback occurs? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v8::Arguments::Length()` will return the number of arguments passed from JavaScript. The `v8::Arguments&` variable is accessed using an array subscript.

```
for (int32_t index = 0; index < arguments->Length(); ++index) {
  if (arguments[index]->IsString()) {
    ::printf("%s\n", *v8::String::Utf8Value(arguments[index]->ToString()));
  }
}
```

You will find an online version of the `v8::Arguments` documentation at http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Arguments.html, however I make no guarantees that it is current or will remain online.

Running the following command from the top of the V8 source tree will generate the documentation locally using [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

```
$ cd include && doxygen -g && doxygen
```

If doxygen executes successfully you can access the documentation in `include/html/index.html`.